# Expected primary-expression before '-' token

Tags: c++, parsing

However I don't have this token ('-') in my code. All I'm doing is attempting to assign a variable of a `colors` enum class type, one of the possible values of `colors` in each case, and I'm getting this error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '-' token
```

In each first statement of each case statement.Can someone explain this error and why it's happening?

**Complete code:**

**Source file**

```
#include "Bunny.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Bunny::Bunny() : radioactive_mutant_vampire_bunny(false), age(0)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    if(rand()%100 + 1 <= 2)
        radioactive_mutant_vampire_bunny = true;
    switch(rand()%4 + 1){
    case 1:
        color = colors.WHITE;
        break;
    case 2:
        color = colors.BROWN;
        break;
    case 3:
        color = colors.BLACK;
        break;
    case 4:
        color = colors.SPOTTED;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "The number entered is outside the range of 1 to 4.";
        break;
    }
    name = names[rand()%names.size()];
}

Bunny::~Bunny()
{
    //dtor
}
```

**Header**

```
#ifndef BUNNY_H
#define BUNNY_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Bunny
{
    public:
        Bunny();
        virtual ~Bunny();
    protected:
    private:
        enum class sex{MALE, FEMALE};
        sex sex;
        enum class colors{WHITE, BROWN, BLACK, SPOTTED};
        colors color;
        int age;
        string names[6] = {"Berry", "Jerry", "Terry", "Marie", "Perry", "Kerry"};
        string name;
        bool radioactive_mutant_vampire_bunny;
};

#endif // BUNNY_H
```

Comment: Instead of using C-style arrays, consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about a hyphen and not a dot?

Comment: I started off with Java and got the syntax mixed up. In Java it would be correct to use the `.` operator and I forgot that it's `::` in C++

Answer (score 1):

- `colors.WHITE` is Java style. In C++ you should write like `colors::WHITE`.
- `names.size()` is invalid because `names` is not a class but an array.

Try this:

```
Bunny::Bunny() : radioactive_mutant_vampire_bunny(false), age(0)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    if(rand()%100 + 1 <= 2)
        radioactive_mutant_vampire_bunny = true;
    switch(rand()%4 + 1){
    case 1:
        color = colors::WHITE;
        break;
    case 2:
        color = colors::BROWN;
        break;
    case 3:
        color = colors::BLACK;
        break;
    case 4:
        color = colors::SPOTTED;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "The number entered is outside the range of 1 to 4.";
        break;
    }
    name = names[rand()%(sizeof(names)/sizeof(*names))];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    enum class sex{MALE, FEMALE};
    sex sex;
```

The name of the `enum class` is `sex`, you can't use `sex` again, rename your member: `sex _sex;`

```
case 1:
    color = colors.WHITE;
    break;
case 2:
    color = colors.BROWN;
    break;
case 3:
    color = colors.BLACK;
    break;
case 4:
    color = colors.SPOTTED;
    break;
```

This is not how `enum classes` work. Use the `::` operator instead of the `.` operator.

Your `strings` array is a plain C array, a plain array doesn't have a `size()` method, either make it a `vector` or use the `sizeof` idiom to check for array length.